Create a contains lambda expression for a dynamic type
I am trying to create a Contains filter LambdaExpression.
The type of the class will be identified at runtime and stored in a Type variable as follows:
Type ModelClassType; //type of the class is assigned at runtime to this variable

The expression I am trying to create is:
x => AwaitingTasksIDs.Contains(x.WfmTaskID.Value)

But since the WfmTaskID is nullable and for simplicity I am trying to create the lambda as follows:
    var propertyName = "WfmTaskID";
    var methodInfo = typeof(List<Guid?>).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(Guid?) });
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(ModelClassType);//ModelClassType is a Type variable and is set at runtime dynamically
    var member = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var constant = Expression.Constant(AwaitingTasksIDs);
    Expression Body = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(AwaitingTasksIDs), methodInfo, member);
    var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<dynamic, bool>>(Body, parameter);

At the last line of code:
    var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<dynamic, bool>>(Body, parameter);

I get the following error message at runtime:
ParameterExpression of type 'Kar.Model.Infrastructure.ProjectType' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

what is the actual expression you would like to build look like in plain c#?

@Ivan Petrov this is how I did it statically : AddOrUpdatePredicate(new KeyValuePair<string, Expression<Func<ProjectType, bool>>>("WfmAwaitingTasks", x => AwaitingTasksIDs.Contains(x.WfmTaskID.Value))); but since WfmTaskID is nulable i modified it as mentioned in the question the expression is:  x => AwaitingTasksIDs.Contains(x.WfmTaskID.Value)

I could solve it by using another overload of Expression.Lambda that takes the delegate type as a type rather than a generic and creates the Func on the fly.
So by changing:
 var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<dynamic, bool>>(Body, parameter);

to:
var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda(Body, parameter);

the issue was resolved.
